# sed/awk how to search text and replace line excluding a block of text

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file as follows

```
PARAMETER=VALUE
PARAMETER1=VALUE

[START]
PARAMETER=VALUE

[END]
```

I wish to use sed to search for `PARAMETER` with exact match and replace the whole line with new text. But I want to exclude the same `PARAMETER` if its between `[START]` and `[END]`

Would you be able to help construct the `sed` or `awk` command

Comment: Can you let us know what have you tried from your end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed '/^\[START\]/,/^\[END\]/!s/^PARAMETER=.*/replacement/'
```

Explanation:

- `/^\[START\]/,/^\[END\]/` : matches all sections starting with `[START]` and ending with `[END]`
- `!` : negates the address, i.e. matches all lines outside the section(s)
- `s/^PARAMETER=.*/replacement/` : replaces every line that starts with `PARAMETER=`

Example:

```
$ cat input.txt
PARAMETER=VALUE
PARAMETER1=VALUE

[START]
PARAMETER=VALUE

[END]
$ sed '/^\[START\]/,/^\[END\]/!s/^PARAMETER=.*/replacement/' input.txt
replacement
PARAMETER1=VALUE

[START]
PARAMETER=VALUE

[END]
$
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk using `f`lag:

```
$ awk '
/^PARAMETER/ && f!=1 { $0="THE REPLACEMENT" } # replace when flag not raised 
/\[START\]/ { f=1 }                             # raise flag at marker
/\[END\]/ { f=0 }                               # flip flag at the other
1' file                                       # output
THE REPLACEMENT
THE REPLACEMENT

[START]
PARAMETER=VALUE

[END]
```

**Edit** Added the one-liner_

```
$ awk '/^PARAMETER/&&f!=1{$0="THE REPLACEMENT"}/\[START\]/{f=1}/\[END\]/{f=0}1' file
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question.. but how would I re-write this in a single line ? I am trying to execute this under a SSH command and its failing with the following error

Comment: Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...

Comment: In this case just remove the comments and the newlines and most of the spaces to make it look cool and tight!. I'll add it to the end.

Comment: @JamesBrown You need to escape `[` and `]` with a backslash to match those characters literally. As it is now, any character in the words "START" and "END" will start/end a section.

Answer (score 0):

@Prashant:try: Though not much difference between James's code and my code. Only thing is I am going for your words like to match the string exactly "PARAMETER" not to match string "PARAMETER1".

```
awk -F"=" '/\[END\]/{A=""} /\[START\]/{A=1} !A && $1 == "PARAMETER"{print "NEW_VALUES";next} 1'  Input_file
```

Here I am making field separator as "=" then looking for string START in a line if yes then making a variable A's value as 1. Looking for string END in a line and making variable A's value to NULL. So then checking condition if variable A's value is NULL and $1 is PARAMETER then printing the new value and giving next to skip further statements. Putting 1 will print all the lines(off course which are not changed with new values, because when new values are getting printed then program is not reaching till 1 so it will not print there).